# Looking for an external monitor for my late 2008 aluminium macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, display, bluetooth, displayport

I have the above laptop and thinking of getting a new, larger monitor to go with it. I have already reviewed other threads here and elsewhere, but there are a few things I am not clear about...
The Macbook has a mini displayport, so I will need an adapter. If I wish images AND sound to be available, which adapter will work (best)? M-DP to HDMI or DVI? I couldn't find a definitive answer...
Also, if I want to use the laptop in clamshell mode, how am I supposed to connect a new keyboard (I have a bluetooth one in the house) and a mouse to it?

Answer (score 1):

[This Samsung 27in monitor](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-27-led-hd-monitor-glossy-black/3441014.p?id=1219581291863&skuId=3441014) should suit your needs.

It's got a fast 4ms response time, good brightness, and it's pretty large, 27 inches.

Get a [Mini DisplayPort to HDMI connector](http://www.amazon.ca/Micropac-105311-Mini-Displayport-Adapter/dp/B0025V2VO0) which carries both video and audio.

Turn on and set up your Bluetooth devices which should still keep connected while the laptop is in lid-closed mode, or you can connect a keyboard and mouse through the USB ports or a USB hub.